# Making custom LINQ extension on dynamic type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, extension-methods

I have the following code:

```
dynamic users = BLClass.MYBLMethod();
List<string> usernames = BLClass.MYBLSecondMethod();
foreach (string username in usernames)
{
    users[username].test();
}
```

I am fetching users(dynamic type) from a BL method. Next from other method I am fetching list of usernames. After that I am applying foreach on list of usernames. In this loop I am calling a method "test". This "test" method will be used in my JavaScript code. Now my question is **how can I convert the above code to some extension method like this**:

```
BLClass.SomeExtensionMethod(methodname)
```

i.e my SomeExtensionMethod will cover the following logic in it:

```
dynamic users = BLClass.MYBLMethod();
List<string> usernames = BLClass.MYBLSecondMethod();
foreach (string username in usernames)
{
    users[username].methodname();
}
```

Can you help me making this extension?

EDIT:

My goal is to have **BLClass.SomeExtensionMethod(methodname)** . I will pass the method name in it and ther inner code(inside the extension) should call this code :

```
users[username].methodname();
```

Comment: I have to use this code at multiple places. Its better to make an extension for it.

Comment: It's not quite clear to be what you want to do. Which type do you want to extend? Your code samples are both the same!

Comment: I want to make custom extension "BLClass.SomeExtensionMethod().test()
"

Comment: So the method should be named `test`, and the type you want to expend is whatever the return value of `SomeExtensionMethod` is? What type is it?

Comment: I have edited my question. I will pass method name say test or test2 or test3 and the following line users[username] should call that method accordingly like users[username].test() or users[username] .test2

Comment: OK, still one question: `BLClass` is the type you want to extend? Or is it a static class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your types look like, but you can call a method by its name using [`GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s2kzbw8.aspx).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SomeExtensionMethod(this BLClass blclass, string methodname)
    {
        dynamic users = blclass.MYBLMethod();
        List<string> usernames = blclass.MYBLSecondMethod();
        foreach (string username in usernames)
        {
            var user = users[username];
            user.GetType().GetMethod(methodname).Invoke(user, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to do this...

```
public class 1 {
    public void method(){
        //do stuff
    }
}

public class 2 {
    public void method2(){
        dynamic users = BLClass.MYBLMethod();
        List<string> usernames = BLClass.MYBLSecondMethod();
        foreach (string username in usernames)
        {
             1.method(users[username]);
         }
    }
 }
```

Would this be simpler?